# ⌘T does not open a new tab

Tags: finder, macos

In Finder under the File menu, the "New Tab" command has ⌘T as a keyboard shortcut. However, when I use those combination of keys, a new tab does not open. I am currently running Yosemite, but this was also the case when I was running Mavericks. Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed mine didn't either under Mavericks 10.9.5.

Open System Preferences -> Keyboard - Shortcuts tab, Select App shortcuts

Click the `+` button and under `Application:` select `Finder.app`,
under `Menu Title` enter `New Tab` and under `Keyboard Shortcut` enter `⌘T`.

After that in an open Finder window `⌘T` opens a new tab.

Comment: I added the keyboard shortcut, but it still doesn't work.